# Rails ActiveRecord::Migration what is the difference between index: true and add_index?

Tags: activerecord, migration, rails-migrations

What is the difference between

```
t.boolean :is_live, index: true
```

and

```
add_index :table_name, :is_live
```

If there is no difference, how come only the `add_index` is reflected in schema.rb. When I use `index: true`, I can't actually see the index in `schema.rb`. Should I only use the `add_index` method.

When use the `add_index` method, I can see this in my schema.rb

```
add_index "table_name", ["is_live"], name: "index_table_name_on_is_live", using: :blahblah
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short: both do the same job. ìndex: true` just saves you an additional line. Look here https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5262#issuecomment-4329571

Comment: This statement is misleading. Sure, they do the same thing, but not in all circumstances. :index option is for references only (t.references or t.belongs_to). See answer from @Alexey

Answer (score 34):

Just found out that the `:index` option is for references only (`t.references` or `t.belongs_to`). For 'ordinary' column types this option is ignored (that's why indices are not reflected in your schema.db when you used the `:index` option).

For less verbose syntax there is an `index` type:

```ruby
t.index :column_name # extra options may be provided also
```

Comment: so is `t.reference :users, index: true` to same thing as `t.index :users`?

Comment: I would like to know that too. Any anwser?

Comment: Absolutely not the same. The former creates a column named `user_id` and an index for it. The latter creates an index for an existing column named `users`.