# ActiveRecord, what does "index: true" mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm writing a migration that involves a foreign key.  Looking at my colleagues code, I see that he has added the line:  `t.reference :tablename, index: true`

The t.reference part makes sense, but I don't know what `index: true` means.  Can anyone tell me?  I haven't been able to find that in the docs.

Note:  This is not a duplicate of: [Rails ActiveRecord::Migration what is the difference between index: true and add_index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914167/rails-activerecordmigration-what-is-the-difference-between-index-true-and-add) Which only diffs the two, but doesn't explain what they do.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`index: true` adds a database index to the referenced column. For example, if creating a :products table:

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.references :user, index: true
end
```

That will create a non-unique index on the `user_id` column in the `products` table named `index_products_on_user_id`.

Comment: What I was also confused on was what a database index is.  I found the wiki article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) to be helpful.

Comment: @alex0112 If you found the article helpful, please post a new answer sharing your findings and stuff. Some people do not check out the comments.

Comment: For some reason I had to do `t.references` plural for this to work. Not sure why, `rake db:migrate` spit out the error and suggested that I use `references` instead of reference for anyone looking at this using rails 5.X.X - this was also with `--database=postgresql` flag in `rails new` command.